# postgreSQL RETURNING clause VS Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-returning

I moving from different SQL languages and I want to UPDATE a table and to **return** some of its columns as below.

Here is how I done it in postgreSQL  -

```
UPDATE account
SET last_login = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
RETURNING email, created_on, last_login
```

how do I return certain columns in **MS SQL** ?

Comment: Use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This can return both the original and new values in an UPDATE operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried but I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Comment: Did you check the docs? [Examples C through G](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-output-into-with-an-update-statement) are UPDATEs with OUTPUT. What did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE account
SET last_login = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTPUT INSERTED.*, DELETED.last_login
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/47cb5/1)